# can not retrieve part of uri (i am working on kohana)

Tags: php, uri

I have following uri `intranet/student/main/schedule`
I have to take just the name of the directory which is `student`, but when I try

```
basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']);
```

it returns `index.php`, when I try

```
basename($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

it retutns `schedule`. How can I take just `student` or at least `student/main/schedule`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this....

```
$url = 'http://www.examplewebsite.com/intranet/student/main/schedule';
$parsed = parse_url($url);

$exploded = explode('/', $parsed['path']);
$directory = $exploded[2];

echo $directory;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can get directory like this-

```
dirname('c:/Temp/x'); // returns 'c:/Temp'
```

OR
You can try this-

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';
print_r(parse_url($url));
echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
?>
```

It will gives you

```
Array
(
    [scheme] => http
    [host] => hostname
    [user] => username
    [pass] => password
    [path] => /path
    [query] => arg=value
    [fragment] => anchor
)
```